# Locking two scrollviews together with UISwitch

Tags: iphone, switch-statement, scrollview

I'm looking for a little help. I'm usually pretty good at finding what I need, but this one's tricky.

Here's the scene for my test app: I have 2 scrollviews that are 1024x85 and they only move horizontal. I also have a UISwitch below them. Above the scrollviews I have two labels that display the content offset of each scrollview as it moves (so I can see what's going on).

What I want to do: After the user slides each of the views side to side I would like to use the UISwitch to lock those scrollviews together wherever they may be sitting.

This is the updated code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

 CGPoint p = scrollOne.contentOffset;
 CGPoint r = scrollTwo.contentOffset;

 // Print the contentOffset labels
 scrollOneLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", p.x];
 scrollTwoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", r.x];


// If lock is on, the distance between offsets is locked (but limited to max and min)
if (lockSwitch.on) {

    NSInteger offset = scrollOne.contentOffset.x - scrollTwo.contentOffset.x;

    if (scrollView == scrollOne) {

        NSInteger maxOffset = scrollTwo.contentSize.width - scrollTwo.frame.size.width;
        [scrollTwo setContentOffset: CGPointMake(MIN(MAX(0.0,scrollOne.contentOffset.x - offset), maxOffset), 0.0)];

    } else if (scrollView == scrollTwo) {
        NSInteger maxOffset = scrollOne.contentSize.width - scrollOne.frame.size.width;
        [scrollOne setContentOffset: CGPointMake(MIN(MAX(0.0,scrollTwo.contentOffset.x + offset), maxOffset), 0.0)];
    }
}

// If the lock is not on, both move independently
}
```

It locks the scrollviews together, but as soon as I move one of the scrollviews the second scrollview jumps to the same content offset as the first. I'm trying to lock them where they are at that moment instead of lining them up when the user touches one of them.

Thank is in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to keep the offset between the two constant? In that case you need a variable, let's call it `offset`, which would be `scrollOne.contentOffset.x - scrollTwo.contentOffset.x` and after locking them just react to the delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // If lock is on, the distance between offsets is locked (but limited to max and min)
    if (lockSwitch.on) {
         if (scrollView == scrollOne) {
             NSInteger maxOffset = scrollTwo.contentSize.width - scrollTwo.frame.size.width;
             [scrollTwo setContentOffset: CGPointMake(MIN(MAX(0.0,scrollOne.contentOffset.x - offset), maxOffset), 0.0)];
         } else if (scrollView == scrollTwo) {
             NSInteger maxOffset = scrollOne.contentSize.width - scrollOne.frame.size.width;
             [scrollOne setContentOffset: CGPointMake(MIN(MAX(0.0,scrollTwo.contentOffset.x + offset), maxOffset), 0.0)];
         }
    }

    // If the lock is not on, both move independently
}
```

EDIT: You have to set the offset when the UISwitch changes state, not on every scrolling event. Have something like this tied to your UISwitch with the `[addTarget:selector:forControlEvents:]` method. Remember, the offset has to be a global variable in your class.

```
- (void)lockChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *lock = sender;
    if (lock.on) {
        offset = (int)(scrollOne.contentOffset.x - scrollTwo.contentOffset.x);
    } else {
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incase you don't understand, variable offset should be captured when UISwitch lockSwitch is turned on.

Comment: @Henri I'm having some problems with the code. I added the variable 'offset' under (lockSwitch.on) and I get an error: Invalid Operands to binary expression ('CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')). Any ideas?

Comment: There was a typo in there in both cases the scrollOne.contentOffset - offset was supposed to be scrollOne.contentOffset.x - offset. Made an edit, should work now.

Comment: @Henri, Thanks. I made the changes but I don't get the scrollViews to lock. They still move independently when the lockSwitch is on.

Comment: Just tested the code, works, try [scrollOne setContentOffset: ] instead of just scrollOne.contentOffset = ...

Comment: @Henri, Still not working for me. I just updated my code above to show you the whole scrollViewDidScroll method. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Henri, I thought I was doing the variable wrong, You're a GENIUS! Works like a charm! Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @Henri, I have a follow up question about this. Is there a way to change the speed at which scrollTwo moves? In other words, when I slide scrollOne, scrollTwo is not perfectly lined up, it moves half the speed of scrollOne?

Comment: Well, if their content is differently sized, there will be a slight difference. If you find the relationship between the content sizes (divide them or whatnot) and use that fraction as a multiplier when changing the offsets you should be able to make them perfectly lined up. Basically (contentSize.x/contentSize2.x) * the change in offset. It's hard to explain, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @Henri, Not sure that's what I was looking for. Both scrollViews move together perfectly right now. I'm looking to change the speed at which scrollTwo moves when I slide scrollOne. So when I move scrollOne can I make scrollTwo scroll 2x faster than scrollOne? Or 1/2 as slow as scrollOne?

Comment: Sure it would be possible, but it would mean you'd have to calculate relative offset instead of absolute offset you are calculating currently. Basically you need to figure out how much one scrollview scrolled (how much it changed since last didScroll event) and change the other scrollview accordingly, you can multiply/divide this change with any coefficient to reduce/increase the scrolling speed of either scrollview.